# Accidentally Redefined VBA Variable - Dim Copy

Tags: vba, excel, variables, copy

I accidentally declare a variable, which was:

```
Dim copy
```

with which I soon realized would cause problems to my code.  For when I tried to copy cells from workbook to workbook, the .CurrentRegion.Copy function would not come to work anymore, and that each time I type the line of code, the "Copy" would instead be written as

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.copy
```

Instead of

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy    'note the variation in caps
```

So, with that said, I erased my declared variable, tried it again, yet still ended with the same result.  I moved to a different module within the same project, and the same thing continued to happen.  Even until I tried to re-type my entire code on a separate Excel file, the "Copy" functionality still did not work, even though in previous cases before my accidential instantiation, it was working extremely fine.

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, your response would be most helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The variable would not prevent that code you posted from working. To regain capitalisation, simply declare:

```
Dim Copy
```

and compile, then delete the variable.